# Drawing lines/points in cocos2d for iPhone is very slow

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to draw coloured landscape around my game which is dynamically changing its shape and color when player moves on.

Even simple drawing couses framerate to drop to around 10 FPS.

```
-(void) draw {    
    glPointSize(1);
    glColor4ub(100,100,100,255);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i+=1){
        for (int j=0; j<100; j++){
            ccDrawPoint(ccp(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

What could I do to make these operations work faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing custom shapes with ccDrawPoint or ccDrawLine is not very good solution.

The best way to draw custom shape is to draw multiple triangles or even better - multiple polygons.

Check this thread to see how to do it: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/848

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `ccDrawPoint`, and making a new `CGPoint`, 10,000 times a frame, which might cause some slowdown.  Have you seen `ccDrawSquare`?

Comment: Problem is becouse the shape and color is changing during game (there are curves and gradients) .. That's why I am using ccDrawPoint .. I will probably have to draw first, than save drawing to cached Texture .